# SLES install php-oci8 without compile whole php/apache?

Tags: php, linux, oracle, pear, oracle-call-interface

Is there a way to install the oci8-pkg of oracle on Suse Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) without downloading oci8 and compile php with it?

eventually a zypper or pear like installation?

What's up to date?

I saw these following links:

- http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/how-faq-forums/unreviewed-how-faq/455756-installing-oracle-instant-client-11_2-suse-11-4-a.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html
- http://www.howforge.com/how-install-oci8-php-5-ubuntu

the first two are about compiling php, and the last one about installing via pear.

Wich way to choose? Is any of them outdated?

cheers